# Define ID value for dhtmlxList when loading the list

Tags: javascript, php, html, dhtmlx

I would like to define the `id` for each item added through the code below.
The value I would like to define would differ with each record based on the value extracted from the csv.

I am unable to asign the value and the documentation seems to be lacking.

Code:

```
<script>
        var myList;
        function doOnLoad() {
            myList = new dhtmlXList({
                                id:"#data2#",
                container:"data_container",
                template:"#data1#<br/>#data2#"
            });
            myList.load("../clients.csv","csv");
        }
    </script>
```

The below link does have information on changing the ID when adding an item, but not when loading them.
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/list__manipulating_data.html#addingitems

Any assistance would be great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use changeId API

```
myList.load("../common/data.csv","csv", function(){
    var count = this.dataCount();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var item = this.item(this.idByIndex(i));
        this.changeId(item.id, generate_new_id(item));
    }
});
```

here, after data loading, code iterates other all items and change their IDs ( generate_new_id is your function, which returns new id, based on the item objec )